# Creating a Multi-Index / Hierarchical DataFrame from Dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following dictionaries:

```
multilevel_indices = {'foo': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'bar': ['X', 'Y'], 'baz': []}    
column_data_1      = {'foo': [2, 4, 5],       'bar': [2, 3],    'baz': []}
```

How can I create a multi-index DataFrame using these dictionaries?

It should be something like:

```
index_1  index_2     column_data_1
foo      A           2
         B           4
         C           5
bar      X           2
         Y           3
baz      np.NaN      np.NaN
```

### Note:

If `NaN` indices are not supported by Pandas, we can drop the empty entries in the dictionaries above.

Ideally, I would like the DataFrame to capture somehow the fact that those entries are missing if possible. However, the most important thing is being able to index the dataframe using the indices in `multilevel_indices`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `concat`:

```
multilevel_indices = {'foo': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'bar': ['X', 'Y'], 'baz': []}    
column_data_1      = {'foo': [2, 4, 5],       'bar': [2, 3], 'baz': []}

pd.concat([pd.Series(column_data_1[k], index=multilevel_indices[k]) for k in multilevel_indices],
          keys=multilevel_indices.keys())
```

Results in:

```
foo  A    2
     B    4
     C    5
bar  X    2
     Y    3
dtype: float64
```

Also, as @CT Zhu mentioned, in the definitions for `baz`, if you change `[]` to `[None]` you can keep track of those entries:

```
baz  NaN    None
foo  A         2
     B         4
     C         5
bar  X         2
     Y         3
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

The original dataset that you have may not result in `nan` index, but change it a little bit will do.

```
In [137]:

multilevel_indices = {'foo': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'bar': ['X', 'Y'], 'baz': [None]}    
column_data_1      = {'foo': [2, 4, 5],       'bar': [2, 3], 'baz': [None]}
mindex=pd.MultiIndex(levels=[multilevel_indices.keys(),list(chain(*multilevel_indices.values()))],
                     labels=[list(chain(*[[i]*len(v[1]) for i, v in enumerate(multilevel_indices.items())])),
                             range(sum(map(len, multilevel_indices.values())))],
                     names=['index_1',  'index_2'])
print pd.DataFrame(list(chain(*column_data_1.values())), index=mindex, columns=['column_data_1'])


                 column_data_1
index_1 index_2               
baz     NaN                NaN
foo     A                    2
        B                    4
        C                    5
bar     X                    2
        Y                    3

[6 rows x 1 columns]
```